# Access to Render Passes with Python

Tags: python, render-passes

I need to save both the 'Combined' pass and the 'indexOB' pass. Is there a simple way to use it with Python?
I set the path to save my render -

```
bpy.context.scene.render.filepath
```

I can also set the image mode:

```
bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].render.image_settings.color_mode = 'BW'
```

[image]

But how can I select the render pass?

Comment: If you want to *save* the passes, create a file output node in the compositor, done. Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/215487/31447, one of our famous q&a's: [Controling compositor by python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19500/controling-compositor-by-python)

Comment: How to create the file output node: [Output Node with Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14910/output-node-with-python)

Comment: If I use the File output nodes, I can't set the File Subpath value with Python. This means I can't set a propper name for the file.

Comment: You can do whatever you want with the file output node. I'd suggest add more details to your question and what exactly you'd like to do - sounds like a XY question to me. Recommend the following post to understand the concept: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16152/save-all-render-passes-to-exr-image/18406#18406

Comment: I want to automatize the render process. At every frame Blender should:
0. Render the frame
1. Save the render
2. Save the IndexOB pass
3. Save the 'Normal' matcap view;
4. And every image should have the propper name. I think the list of names will be stored in a text file.

Comment: Here is a demo on how to create a new file output node and render all the passes you mentioned into a new 'render' folder automatically: https://pasteall.org/QWvo/raw Does this answer your question?

Comment: I'm afraid no. Still can't understand, how to set my own names for rendered images. The script from pasteall.org/QWvo/raw generates images 'Normal0001.jpg', 'Mist0001.jpg' etc.

Comment: By naming the slot, as I did with the beauty pass (see the for-loop ). What's your issue with those names? The frame suffix "0001"? If so, there is no way around that. You'd have to re-name the files using python afterwards.